# Font-Awesome Not Showing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I can't figure out why my fa-fa symbols won't show. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is a link to my CodePen:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/OWbXLw/

Here is my HTML code:

```
 **<!--Social media links -->
<div class="social-media-icon-footer">

 <div id="contact">
    <div class="contact">
      <h3>Social Media Connections</h3>
      <div>
        <ul class="soc">
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-linkedin-square fa-fw"></i>LINKEDIN</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://github.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>GITHUB</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></i>FACEBOOK</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-fire fa-fw"></i>FREECODECAMP</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>**
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.social-media-icon-footer{
  width:500px;
  background-color:white;
  color: #0099ff;
  height:80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}


/**
    .link-button-holder {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #097BC0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px gray;
    display: block;
    border:1px solid #094BC0;
}
**/

.link-button-holder > a {
    display: inline-table;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;

}
.link-button-holder > a > h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #f7f8f8;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: cabinregular;
    text-align: center;
}

div.contact {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top:-20px;
 /**background-color: black;**/
}

ul.soc {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.soc li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.socbutton a {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px black;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Here is the link to the CodePen I referenced:https://codepen.io/SHENKU360/pen/VedRbP

Here is his html code:

```
<div id="contact">
    <div class="contact">
      <h3>Contact</h3>
      <div>
        <ul class="soc">
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="    https://www.linkedin.com/in/jason-conley-744b27111/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-linkedin-square fa-fw"></i>LINKEDIN</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://github.com/shenku360/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>GITHUB</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jason.conley.9231712/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></i>FACEBOOK</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/shenku360/" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-fire fa-fw"></i>FREECODECAMP</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is CSS code:

```
ul.soc {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.soc li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.socbutton a {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px black;
  width: 250px;
}
```

The fa-fa icons show up on his page, but they won't show up on mine!

Comment: Where you added font-awesome css reference?

Comment: your codepen demo works fine for me, maybe some of your browser add-on block the font-awesome files, try open your demo in a Incognito mode(Ctrl + Shift + N)

Comment: @Hanif, what do you mean? Do you mean the code that I referenced to write my code [link](https://codepen.io/SHENKU360/pen/VedRbP)?

Comment: Yes you added 2 reference I went first reference but in second reference seems working fine in my PC. In which browser's you checking in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click at the Settings in his codepen and you'll see that he imported font-awesome CSS file through codepen's imports. This is what you missed, you're not importing it through codepen settings or through HTML.. you have to do either of these.
[image]

Comment: Wow! I spent almost all of today and these early morning hours, up to now trying to figure this out....I had tried inserting such a link into the head tags in my html file, but it wasn't working in there. Weird why it works when I insert it via the settings tab! Also, is there a way to get or create the FA icons without referencing a link? Because linking to an external library slows down page-load time by a couple seconds....

Comment: sure, just download font-awesome [V4.7.0 ZIP](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip) or [V5.0.2 ZIP](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/fontawesome-free-5.0.2.zip) and extract from it the css folder and the fonts folder and link to the local css from your web page

Answer (score 2):

Have you added font awesome css? I don't see it in your html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs. cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/ css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: no, I didn't use that link, because for the CodePen I referenced, he didn't use it either, and his icons still show....

Comment: is there a way to get or create the FA icons without referencing a link? Because linking to an external library slows down page-load time by a couple seconds....

Comment: I don't think so. Always that you need a custom font you need to include something. But the browser should cache it so it's only downloaded once